# Mysql restrictive

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 variables in PHP (let's call them 'var1' and 'var2') and a sql command like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `table` WHERE `var` = '{$var1}'"
if ($var2) {
  $sql.= "AND `var`={$var2}"; }
```

Variable `var1` it is always set, but var2 not. I want when var 2 is set to apply WHERE clause only for var2. This means that var2 is more restrictive than var1. How can i do this in SQL language.

Comment: Not sure I understand, your code looks correct. Are you wanting to change to `WHERE ``var`` = '{$var2}'`?

Comment: Be aware of SQL injection!

Comment: He has not shown any user input to cause concern for SQL injection @MrTux

Comment: It's bad practice to not use prepared statements or escape contents you feed into a SQL query. And based on the context you don't know that it's not input from any untrusted source. @JayBlanchard

Comment: True, but I also haven't posted the "don't use `mysql_`" functions warning either because we haven't enough to go on here. We don't know that `$var1` and `$var2` aren't the result of escaping things @MrTux

Comment: @JayBlanchard SQL injection musn't only be seen as "attacking", values could include `'` and then this approach fails.

Comment: No doubt @MrTux, but it is obvious to me that the OP has posted semi-pseudo-code for the queries and consequently we can only guess what the real code looks like.

Comment: I don't want to talk too much about this as this discussion is not really helpful: Lots of people don't escape values and then wonder why it's not always working as expected. I just wanted to make the OP aware of this.

Comment: @OsomA did you want this as a pure SQL solution? Or did you want it combined with PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to do this -

```
$sql = "SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `table` ";
if($var2) {
    $sql .= "WHERE `var` = '{$var2}'";
} else {
    $sql .= "WHERE `var` = '{$var1}'";
}
```

If you want to do this just using SQL you would use something like this -

```
SELECT `id`, `name`, `variable`
    CASE variable
        WHEN 'var1' = variable THEN a = var1
        WHEN 'var2' = variable THEN a = var2
    END
FROM `table`
WHERE `foo` = a
```

Without knowing more of your code or having sample data to work with it is hard to develop a demo, but this should get you started.

Comment: then write it in your answer :) Read the question carefuly, he wrote `How can i do this in SQL language.`

Comment: I'm not sure he meant that literally @Xatenev :) I'll ask for clarification.

Comment: Added a pure SQL solution @Xatenev

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($var2) {
    $sql = "SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `table` WHERE `var` = '{$var2}'";

} else {
    $sql = "SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `table` WHERE `var` = '{$var1}'";
}
```

Comment: @Sébastien it did until the user edited the question and added that sentence. Instead of jumping on me like that, maybe you could try and solve the problem ?

Comment: @Xatenev that line was added after my answer. Thanks for doing such a useful job at commenting though.